# Optimization of a large multiselect list

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have three MultiselectLists
Countries which has 22 values
Cities which has ~800 values
Sites which has ~1700 values

I am using the jquery bootstrap-multiselect library
It is fast enough for what I am trying to do that the user doesn't notice any overhead except in one case when the user selects USA 600 Cities and 1200-1300 sites get checked/selected this takes about 30 seconds in IE, and about 6 seconds in Firefox which is enough for a reasonable person to believe that something is wrong with the page.

I don't want to change the UI of the website at all since this works beautifully in every other case, including when the user hits a "select-all" or "deselect-all" and just wants to run a full report

these are the two functions that take about 90-95% of the time to execute

```
getInputByValue: function(value) {
    var checkboxes = $('li input', this.$ul);
    var valueToCompare = value.toString();

    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i = i + 1) {

        var checkbox = checkboxes[i];

        if (checkbox.value === valueToCompare) {
            return $(checkbox);
        }
    }
}

getOptionByValue: function(value) {
    var options = $('option', this.$select);
    var valueToCompare = value.toString();
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i = i + 1) {
        var option = options[i];
        if (option.value === valueToCompare) {
            return $(option);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the code I use to select all of the options, I have a Dictionary>>(); that I pass from my controller into my view that governs the relationship between the Countries/Cities/ and sites

```
onChange: function (option, checked, select) {
        try{
            if (checked == true) {
                var t0 = performance.now();
                $('#Cities').multiselect('select', Object.keys(CountryCitySite[$(option).text()]),'triggeronChange');
                var t1 = performance.now();
                list = Object.keys(CountryCitySite[$(option).text()])
                var t2 = performance.now();
                for(var i = 0; i<list.length; i++)
                {
                    $('#Sites').multiselect('select', CitySite[list[i]])
                }
                var t3 = performance.now();
            }
            else if (checked == false) {
                $('#Cities').multiselect('deselect', Object.keys(CountryCitySite[$(option).text()]), 'triggeronChange');
                list = Object.keys(CountryCitySite[$(option).text()])
                for(var i = 0; i<list.length; i++)
                {
                    $('#Sites').multiselect('deselect', CitySite[list[i]], 'triggeronChange')
                }
            }
        }
```

Some thoughts:
1. maybe in the case of USA I could do an Ajax, and post everything to the server and then return three new selectlists with the appropriate options checked? the problem with this is that I don't see this taking less than like 7 or 8 seconds if not more which is still much too long

2. var options = $('option', this.$select);
   this Jquery selection is several orders of magnitude slower than just using native javascript Document.getelementsbytagname, since I know that all of the checkboxes have unique values maybe I could replace this Jquery selection with native javascript and get all of the checkboxes that way
3. as a 'hack' I could send two invisible multiselectlists at the very beginning with all of the boxes for USA checked, these invisible multiselects behave exactly the same as the visible ones in most respects but if the user selects USA, these are shown instead of the originals. This actually does work, it makes the website a little slower but since the selection of every other option is so quick it doesn't really matter, it seems like a sub-par solution but this is currently the best I have

if anyone thinks of anything else or can give any advice on this I would be very appreciative

Sincerely Josh

Comment: Well one thing you could do, for starters, is cache all those jQuery lookups.

Comment: Also, every time you rebuild the checkbox and option elements, you can create your own map object so that you don't have to do linear searches to find them. That would make those first two routines take like no time at all.

Comment: I understand where you are coming from with the Cacheing, and I thought of that as well, it would make the selectboxes go faster but the problem is that if the User could select 'USA' the very first go-around, before everything is Cached, and this would actually make the first go around go even slower.

the time is no issue for the 2,179 other cases, just this one case, the problem is that it's a pretty frequent case and is basically breaking the website

Comment: You can create the mapping at the same time you're creating the elements.